# What is wrong with my modulo 13 asynchronous up counter?

Tags: digital-logic, counter, ripple-counter

[image]

I'm trying to design a modulo 13 asynchronous up counter with master slave JK flip flops. I connected the NAND gate to clear it when it reaches number 13, as shown in the figure. However, it continues as 10-11-12 and loops. and does not start from 0. Where is my mistake?

[Falstad simulation link.](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAOaAmZYCcB2BzkcBmLUhJBSEJAFiOoFMBaMMAKBuxDRwDZkQTBH27IiaQTmQ0oIGmzC8JVJkpkreOCRIAmDAGYBDAK4AbAC5NTDHeFlUYkdoom8ZqtDLeDN2kHqMzS2tbCAcoWGclcAwfTxiBVS1ufwMTCysbO3DHKIlsCQ8ZAp9k3TSgzND7CKc2AHdZJNd3XygGkG9mhNLlDrBY7pLuyDYAc07W5K6cSHV2xu6iOd6QcQcO1RoqGi6EWN31Tb4BQ59tuW9RxZO1tBVbs+vBZDg1-nOqIg-n1QReO6CfYCcQLSQfUF-AGg363MA0dy3GFsAAyQKwhWW7gQGMEPGUdnMACdjAxqO00VDAVSWACqBBiaTyb9gXcVKynptWfDsbFkYsiPsQFgAUxBRIsWCxULJUxPF8Vr86BKVtKVUcBULFCoMAJtVLleBeCpxUaNmAEBAhLF9UxDfqvrIEApLUC+arDZLHRQubE0P83QJdVLuSJrUHIAIlaD-aLPYrNobY4HuJGDaDbUm09HtGnw9wA6MLVa3PTjSmHSkfcXPmtVayvVXqJtS+Aw63g78OwRa98oy6rXDy0Ny97mzWmEjVW1G-QqM7Fq2eatl13ksuRxtF2Ue0sE9uJfde0fYR8wGHbvd+zcPsHJ7fCy2ygHup2n9oX5fs+-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-o-WSGN4m5oX8ndDVAUlTm+kaDNcRFqWedoomvg2wWQRWFWRsaHn9X1gW9fLA2bURmtQXWHorcdedDKZrb+bpFn+nLSV9Up5WTdxD2ExrD2j3xSGJGrV0DZEIO-s02D5dveIg6D55gr+4L2al1OyjKUWOgziUIV17h11xBPs8aBPM-VdoayDq3gptmC7er9dGbPZn6BoaBSC77ue4I1nk5EAG5v+mg9W62ao5z-OdlHwqOiHq2ernxoh5BuRZ5tjpI-LIPZ+eGvHuSUeNjRZdZ9XWQGRJMk9Jz-I3ZIsLQXPji9-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-zvnMP9hc92rzK5jmdLCtyptnlzJjk8++9IlHYvwRPE2ZDekIrwQ9WaTU9a4tJWgmQFLFHKK2lSuloLuLFDhXLCF1Cjwss5KfOAIJ8j8sEINekIBGQ3zBNMjiIyOUytOWmfk8qBWcqAZKsJZ49k-A6DKqgokSJXBybNM4KzOR6y2cai5prEmVwaQXc8xdllCURf0CSb1z78QBEPSBSFV6uvXu83gO1f4+rfsbMJWo-Wmm5q8OG+1UVIMDUTcAMajRwMTT0RQ8V7KnxTYNMSeYYSEmvsyfoHrSVlq9aW1FNoy0iq3mvLiaA15pSbbNYM7N46lNTDGHsrbtBdr7ay7gILbFl0gBmcRa9VyGWwKi8R468I6LkJ3Xuq6+4zrLe2hd2z4nXM3b4zdXMq1qzjUdDl9wYwXAvf2sK16pL0lrcdLe27lx3pKPvF9Pt93mjDn65cs6rHzAJMi39na9Sbpylcl16D6R+sTtB0i65I1CiLGHdN-6nVDqRTO9NxVMOdgbgsv9-MfaxG5phw2PtR1tmLs3B17zMPu0jbtTNJ7WP7Q5ex7eqULjkeLr4-DR69b4d8ehp9wmv1dSo8rCjPtcO8ZnfgYoHF2MX3mc6BCFoIRal4OGgkMA9H3E8Q9eg9xfFuRJu4oztKm2pmceILwAS9ao0dnqJTPReLgFRl4egFoTG6f8eYxT10WqpUg+p+ts1gbuYgf0GL9J3PTuc9p-I-xP6cbSzArzIWhPZd-glqC5UtNwwK+luBLnSXubpU2lBk7Gb-zLina6Fprqe3K615r7mW0jtImnLDqJhViXcH1lgQ28SFjsEYUwABnCVRVRM6guGKAuS8-pLzVHAml7V4TxDFBrMufXX0jbpXKJbVtTvsnE3iJbagmi3fmxoXbbUhBXa6LdrolbGgfdnutz71BhxD3W1GzWcQ+aJDGmLcHE8ttCFmtzGHY0dvuFVnAg6t3hhL25gdJeHbsQcNx0CCOx3doE6EBHW4ZPpo8GUggFTCOyPv129yBHcOt4U7Gr90NhdlLQIu4IOhXnqHawqzzZ4xBAP6KAeVZaJXhWIKlHlDceU0pZSHaru0YVxf5S1ziDLQvigVd1+VtyRuddXbN4UHmRvfhW4OlgDi1vWIO4Oqwa6juYZjaN6N66cpS6DZ9yNvKvupbq8D4MLnMvAFy4EO7o0IbAYWYNYUo13hd6xflrA-MVrkFscy8DxoiORB8LCnKZZw4gr-39ls0JxQzlbJ2OSVmBP-2QADDXtNMT0VyHT9diC1qUBJ-++DJVA-lZEvpHMGJg+Vkz5NvX12E+YMoGREAA)

Comment: I'm guessing it's an error related to propagation time.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved, increase the duty cycle of the clock. And secondly add a delay buffer to the output of the nand gate

Comment: I was trying out the same but had hard time working with falstad. But glad you found out already ;)

Comment: It will be good if you add an external clear switch as well to start the counter at 0.  NAND gate output ANDed with external clear = global clear signal.